# Decrypting core data

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, encryption, nsmutabledictionary

Warning: I don't know obj C but was handed this project for this one task

I am successfully encrypting the fields which lay in core data (sqlite) but I cannot decrypt them using a similar method. Below is my code which is causing the app to break during the fetch of core data:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self getContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
if (predicate != nil) {
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
}
NSError *error;
//the code that breaks
NSMutableDictionary *theFetch = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
return [[self decryptDictionaryData:theFetch withUserId:entityDesc.propertiesByName[@"theUnlockKey"]] mutableCopy];
```

decryptDictionaryData goes through each key in the dictionary and decrypts as follows:

```
decryptedResult = [RNDecryptor  decryptData:[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:value options:0]
                                       withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                           password:key
                                              error:&error];
```

Comment: There's no way to tell what's going on without seeing the implementation of `decryptDictionaryData:withUserId:`.

Comment: That said, my gut sense is that the current approach doesn't actually make the data any more secure. I would strongly advise against hand-rolling your own encryption scheme like this.

Comment: @mattt I'll update the question with the contents of decryptDictionaryData, I'm using RNCryptor for the encryption

Comment: This does absolutely nothing to make the application safer, and only works to decrease performance. iOS has built-in APIs to secure your data, like NSFileProtectionComplete. Use them instead.

Comment: Define "causing the app to break".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Add the encryption code. What is the Core Data data type used? Why Base64 encoding?

Comment: your first issue is that executeFetchRequest returns an array not a dictionary.